# LUBUNTU Freezing Randomly

Tags: freeze

I need help. I have a Laptop , where I have a dual boot of Windows Vista and of Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

I have used several Distros all based on Debian and in all of them the problem remains.

At this moment the pc freezes randomly and I can't use anything except the mouse or the keyboard and I have to restart it by force.

Before, I used Ubuntu and the same thing happened,sometimes even on the login screen after logging in, I also used PureOS and after 5 minutes of use more or less and the same thing happened,in tails live usb the same, now I use Lubuntu and the same happens but in Lubuntu it takes more, like 20-40 minutes before freezing.

I tried to update drivers and kernel and it didn't work, I tried Nomodeset and it didn't work. NOTHING seems to work.

No driver appears in the software and updates tab.

Laptop info:
Name    EasyNote TE11BZ
Family  ASPIRE
Vendor  Packard Bell
Version V2.05
Processor   AMD E-300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
Memory  3591MB (824MB used)
Machine Type    Notebook
Operating System    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Resolution  1366x768 pixels
Kernel  Linux 5.4.0-59-generic (x86_64)
Version #65~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 14 15:59:40 UTC 2020
C Library   GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) 2.27

Output off `uname -a` command:

`Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-59-generic #65~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 14 15:59:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Output off `free` command:

````
Mem:        3591772      649904     2184168       81352      757700     2640408
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148 ```


Output off ``` lsblk ``` command:

``` NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0 307,2G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   513M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   512M  0 part 
└─sda6   8:6    0 157,5G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   ```


Output off ``` smartctl ``` command:



``` smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-59-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus 5400.6
Device Model:     ST9500325AS
Serial Number:    S2WP21ZC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0523182a2
Firmware Version: 0001SDM1
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Jan  7 19:51:58 2021 WET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 137) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x103b) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       149161701
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1108
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       30
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   080   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       101953717
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2693
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1086
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   069   049   045    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 30/31)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       67
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       220
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   076   076   000    Old_age   Always       -       48851
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   031   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (0 11 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   048   036   000    Old_age   Always       -       149161701
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay. ```
````

Comment: What do your syslog, journalctl, and dmesg say at the time of the freeze?

Comment: it crashed right now at 20:18 
syslog :https://pastebin.pl/view/ea5d302d
journalctl: https://pastebin.pl/view/9a7f3e19
dmesg output: https://pastebin.pl/view/1716f0cb

Comment: You have 30 re-allocated sectors showing in the SMART data (attribute No 5) and attribute 191 (G-Sense Error Rate) shows value of 67. Your hard drive may need proper testing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can i do that? Im a bit noob to a ll this

Comment: @user111667 And do you think that the problem that causes the freeze is that?

Comment: I have bought a new hard drive and the problem continues

Answer (score 2):

When you boot Ubuntu and it lands in the GRUB menu (it might not - you will then  have to google to find how to display the GRUB menu) you can select whatever OS but also there is (? should be) a Memtest86+ option at the bottom of the list. Select that and set it going.

This test will extensively test the RAM in your machine and tells you if it is broken. It will take from a while to a really long time depending on your setup.

If its not HDD and not RAM then it will be some other hardware problem not as easily tracked down or fixed! from the sound of it (random stops) it is almost certainly the RAM.

Comment: Thank you very much! Im going to the the memtest now, but if it is hardware issue why does my windows works fine and only happens to linux ? Its very weird.